# How to calculate IOPS in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In Azure I know that I can get 20k IOPS per storage account. If I need more IOPS then I can add more storage accounts and spread my data across them.  Up to 100 storage accounts and 2 million IOPS.

How do I calculate my IOPS needs with AWS S3?  Assume maximum distribution via GUIDs as keys to get max IOPS.

Comment: IOPS only applies to EBS volumes and not to S3.